# How to draw a solid colored circle?

Tags: circles

I am working on some book writing. For that I need to draw circle filled with red color.

I tried `\circle` but it generate black circle only. How can I fill it with color?

Comment: use the `tikz` package

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Try `\circle*`. Or add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: If you've already loaded _color_ or _xcolor_ (or a package that automaticall loads it, such as _TikZ_) you could also use the `\textcolor` command, e.g. `\textcolor{red}{$\bullet$}`

Answer (score 95, accepted):

One easy way would be to use `TikZ` as in the following MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
Some Text \tikz\draw[red,fill=red] (0,0) circle (.5ex); further text
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

Where the first `red` defines the line style of the drawn circle to be red and the `fill=red` specifies, that its solid red. You could also use `black,fill=red` to obtain a red circle with a black border. Finally of course the `.5ex` is the radius of the circle.

Answer (score 34):

Another solution with TikZ, but this one creates a command `\tikzcircle` to be used in the document:

```
\newcommand{\tikzcircle}[2][red,fill=red]{\tikz[baseline=-0.5ex]\draw[#1,radius=#2] (0,0) circle ;}%
```

It takes one mandatory argument, the radius of the circle and an optional argument that helps in customizing the circle's aspect.

The code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\tikzcircle}[2][red,fill=red]{\tikz[baseline=-0.5ex]\draw[#1,radius=#2] (0,0) circle ;}%

\begin{document}
This is my text \tikzcircle{2pt} followed by \tikzcircle[green, fill=blue]{1.5pt} some other text \tikzcircle[fill=orange]{3pt} and some other text
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Note that if you draw the line around the circle instead in addition to filling the interior, the visible diameter of the circle will be one linewidth more than `2*radius`.

Comment: Yes you're right, but I think for the purpose having the exact radius is not such a strict constraint.

Answer (score 16):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,pict2e}% to allow any radius
\begin{document}
\leavevmode
\put(0,0){\circle{20.6}}\put(0,0){\color{red}\circle*{20}}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 15):

`\newcommand\filledcirc{\ensuremath{{\color{red}\bullet}\mathllap{\circ}}}` gives you a  `\circ` filled with red color. You need `usepackage{mathtools}` for the `\mathllap` command.

To change the border color as well, just change the color of the `\circ`, like so: `\newcommand\filledcirc{\ensuremath{{\color{red}\bullet}\mathllap{\color{blue}\circ}}}`.

The advantage over Tikz solutions is that it's *much* faster.

Comment: this gives an error: `missing $ inserted`

Comment: @banan3'14 I've added `\ensuremath{...}` to the commands. Now they should work outside of a math environment as well.

Answer (score 1):

Put these two lines right after the \begin{document} command:

```
\setlength{\unitlength}{1mm}

\newcommand{\Newdot}{{\leavevmode\put(0,.63){\circle*{2.5}}}}
```

Then, anywhere in your document, you can put a big black dot with the `\Newdot` command.

```
...
\Newdot
...
```

This is for black dots.  You can adjust the centering with the arguments of the `\put(*,*)` command, and adjust the size of the dot with the argument of the `\circle*(*)` command.

Color changes are addressed with `\color{*}` command as explained in previous comments.