# Customize a section title with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, sectioning

I am trying to get this kind of result with tikz. However I don' have any idea how to align the text with the bottom of the rectangles or how to anchor the 2nd rectangle with the line of the title [image: Final result]

In this example, the fist title is a section title, the 2nd, a subsection title.

```
%!TEX program = xelatex
    \documentclass{memoir}
    \usepackage\[paperwidth=10.5cm,paperheight=15.5cm, margin=0.9cm\]{geometry}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage\[explicit\]{titlesec}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \definecolor{sec}{HTML}{DD5C14}
    \definecolor{band}{HTML}{EE9C52}

    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \newfontfamily{\helveticacdb}{Helvetica-CondensedBlack}
    % \newfontfamily{\helveticacdl}{Helvetica-CondensedLight}

    \usepackage\[T1\]{fontenc}

    \titleformat{\section}\[hang\]{\helveticacdb\fontsize{1.2cm}{0.95cm}\bfseries}{}{0.5ex}%
      {\begin{minipage}{0.975\textwidth}%
      \noindent
      \color{band}%
      \llap{\vrule width0.7cm height 0.7cm depth0ex\hskip0.25ex}%
      \textcolor{sec}{\unskip#1}%
      \hskip0.25ex%
      \rlap{\vrule width\textwidth height 0.7cm    depth0ex}%
    \end{minipage}}\[\smallskip\]

    \titleformat{\subsection}\[hang\]{\helveticacdb\fontsize{0.45cm}{0.5cm}\bfseries}{}{0.5ex}%
      {\noindent%
      \color{band}%
      \raisebox{0.222ex}{\hbox to \textwidth{%
      \vrule width1.3ex height1ex depth0ex\hskip0.5ex%
      \raisebox{-0.222ex}{\textcolor{sec}{#1}}%
      \hskip0.75ex%
      \leaders\vrule height 0.2cm depth0ex\hfil}}}\[\smallskip\]

    \titleformat{\subsubsection}\[hang\]{\helveticacdb\fontsize{0.3cm}{0.3cm}\bfseries}{}{0.5ex}{
      \textcolor{sec}{\unskip#1}%
    }%

    % Remove the header while starting a new section
    \let\footruleskip\undefined
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    % \renewcommand{\sectionmark}\[1\]{\markright{#1}{}}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
    \fancyhf{}
    \renewcommand{\sectionmark}\[1\]{\markboth{\chaptername \ \thesection. #1}{}}
    % \lhead{\leftmark}

    % Start sections on a new page
    \usepackage{etoolbox}
    \patchcmd{\section}{plain}{empty}{}{}
    \pretocmd{\section}{%
      \ifnum\value{section}=0 \else\clearpage\fi
    }{}{}
    % manage multicolumns after each section title
    \usepackage{multicol}

    \AtBeginDocument{\begin{multicols}{2}}
    \AtEndDocument{\end{multicols}}

    \makeatletter
    \let\subsection@orig\subsection
    \renewcommand\subsection\[1\]{\endmulticols\subsection@orig{#1}\multicols{2}}
    \makeatother

    \begin{document}
    \section\[Politique et économie\]{Politique\\ et économie}
      \subsection{POLITIQUE}
        \subsubsection{First subsub}
          \lipsum\[1-2\]

    \end{document}
```

[image: result]

**Remaining issues:**

- Clear the page number each time a new section appears.
- Stick the left orange **square** to the left border page.

Comment: You can create them with overlay pictures that are positioned relative to the start and end of the text and the current page. Have a look at overlays in the TikZ picture. The following draws an arrow from the current position, to the left margin. `\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture] \draw[->] coordinate (here) (here) -- (current page.west|-here); \end{tikzpicture}` When you implement this, make sure the rectangles bleed into the margin.

Comment: How can I get the coordinates of the point at the west part of the page and under the header ?

Comment: Additionally to Marc van Dongen (using `page.` coordinates) you can use `titlesec` to change font sizes of the section/subsection and the TikZ option `baseline` (see e.g. here http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89827/8042) to align the boxes with respect to the bottom line or the center line of the text accordingly.

Comment: After `\tikz coordinate (first reference point);Your section title here\tikz coordinate (second reference point);` You can then add your rectangles using the labels `first reference pint` and `second reference point` and positioning relative to `current page.east` and `current page.west`.

Comment: @Ronny I'm sure this is possible but that's not what the OP was asking. I just wanted to show something to get started with.

Comment: I noticed I made a type in my first comment. I should have written _have a look at overlays in the TikZ manual,_ not _...in the TikZ picture,_

Comment: Mine was also only meant as a starting point. Haven't tried that yet, but that would be my starting point.  Another approach to your `\tikz coordinates` would be `tikzmark`s - though the result is the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without TikZ. Still far from perfect though.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[paperwidth=10.5cm,paperheight=15.5cm,headheight=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\definecolor{sec}{HTML}{DD5C14}
\definecolor{band}{HTML}{EE9C52}

\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\sffamily\Huge\bfseries}{}{0.5ex}%
  {\begin{minipage}{0.975\textwidth}%
  \noindent
  \color{band}%
  \llap{\vrule width\textwidth height1ex depth0ex\hskip0.75ex}%
  \textcolor{sec}{\unskip#1}%
  \hskip0.75ex%
  \rlap{\vrule width\textwidth height1ex depth0ex}%
\end{minipage}}[\smallskip]

\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\sffamily\Large\bfseries}{}{0.5ex}%
  {\noindent%
  \color{band}%
  \raisebox{0.222ex}{\hbox to 0.975\textwidth{%
  \vrule width2ex height1ex depth0ex\hskip0.5ex%
  \raisebox{-0.222ex}{\textcolor{sec}{#1}}%
  \hskip0.75ex%
  \leaders\vrule height1ex depth0ex\hfil}}}[\smallskip]

\begin{document}
\section[Politique et \'economie]{Politique \\ et \'economie}

Blablabla \ldots le politique et l'\'economie

\subsection{POLITIQUE}

Quelle horreur!

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: One remaining issue: how can I get a left square collapsing the left border of the page.