# How do I type dots of different sizes?

Tags: symbols

I need to type very big dots like the ones in the text below. How do I do that for both the filled-in and the empty-interior versions?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Tex.SE! Can you share your code as a Minimal Working Example(MWE)? That way, it helps us to understand the problem better and you will get better answers faster.

Comment: If you do not want to load packages, you could do e.g. `\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\mybullet}{\raisebox{-0.18ex}{\textbullet}}
\newcommand{\mycirc}{\raisebox{-0.18ex}{\ensuremath{\circ}}}
\begin{document}
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{0.9\textwidth}
Blub {\Large\mybullet} bla {\Huge\mybullet} blub {\Large\mycirc}
bla {\Huge\mycirc}.
\end{minipage}}
\end{document}` but if you load packages like pgf there will be more convincing ways.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
$\circ $
$\bullet$
$\bigcirc$
Some Text \tikz\draw[black,fill=black] (0,0) circle (1ex); more text
\end{document}
```

which gives: [image]

Also check: [How to draw a solid colored circle?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89821/how-to-draw-a-solid-colored-circle) and for ams-math docs: http://ftp.acc.umu.se/mirror/CTAN/info/short-math-guide/short-math-guide.pdf .

Answer (score 3):

In standard math mode, you can use `\circ` for a small white dot and `\bullet` for a small black one. Using the package `wasysym`, you can use `Circle` and `CIRCLE` commands for the big ones. 
[image]
Note that [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) is a great tool to find symbols. There also exists a lot of lists of LaTeX symbols, like [this one](http://www.rpi.edu/dept/arc/training/latex/LaTeX_symbols.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

You can use some glyphs from `mathabx`without loading the package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry} 

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathb}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathb}{m}{n}{ <-6> mathb5 <6-7> mathb6 <7-8>
mathb7 <8-9> mathb8 <9-10> mathb9 <10-12> mathb10 <12-> mathb12 }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathb}{U}{mathb}{m}{n}
 %
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{ <-6> mathx5 <6-7> mathx6 <7-8>
mathx7 <8-9> mathx8 <9-10> mathx9 <10-12> mathx10 <12-> mathx12 }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\newmoon} {\mathord}{mathb}{"4D}%swapped in the original file
\DeclareMathSymbol{\fullmoon} {\mathord}{mathb}{"4E}%swapped in the original file
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bigovoid} {\mathop}{mathx}{"EC}

\newcommand{\Circ}{$\vcenter{\hbox{$\newmoon\;$}}$}
\newcommand{\CIRC}{${\bigovoid}\;$}
\newcommand{\thickdot}{$\vcenter{\hbox{$\fullmoon\;$}}$}
\newcommand{\DOT}{$\vcenter{\hbox{\Large$\fullmoon\:$}}$}

\begin{document}

\fbox{\parbox{0.9\linewidth}{Here the vertices are indicated according to their heights, where \DOT denotes a vertex of height $3$, \thickdot denotes height $2$, \Circ denotes height $1$ and \CIRC denotes height $0$. }}

\end{document}
```

[image]